# play 2.0 auto apply test mode conf

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

My application will upload file to S3, but I want it to upload to another bucket when running in test mode (play test). Is there any workaround for this? I saw in play 1.x has a feature called application ids. But I couldn't find it under 2.0 documentations.

when running test mode, play will use 'test.s3.bucket' instead of 's3.bucket'.

**application.conf**

```
s3.bucket=prodbucket
test.s3.bucket=testbucket
```

EDIT:
Besides #kheraud answer, Application provides isProd(), isTest(), and isDev().

```
String bucketName = (Play.application().isProd())
                ? Play.application().configuration().getString("s3.bucket")
                : Play.application().configuration().getString("dev.s3.bucket");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have access to the running mode with (not tested):

```
import play.api.Play.current

val targetBukkett = if(play.api.Play.application.mode == "Dev") {
    test.s3.bucket
} else {
    s3.bucket
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointer. I found a method isProd() in Play.Application.